# Как запустить Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Здраствуйте. Пользуюсь Hortonworks sandbox 2.6, и возникла проблема с запуском jar-ников написаных для spark2. До этого пользовался версией 2.3.2 и там была файловая система разделена на локальную и hdfs и было понятно(с 100500 раза) как запускать(хотя запускал только MR задачи ну думаю spark бы тоже проблем не было б). В новой же версии файловая система не разбита, и куда ложить джарник не понятно(куда только не пихал). И ищё не понятние как правильно написать команду для запуска джарника. Ясень что прочитал кучу туториалов и половина с разными командами(а именно то --master to --deploy-mode разные), а пока из за неопытность различия мне не понятны.
Если есть кто сталкивался с HDP 2.6 розтолкуйте

1. куда ложить джарники
2. как правильно команду написать
3. и ищё, джарники вроде ж обычные(тоесть только мои классы) без стороних библиотек?

Фото файловой системы в Ambari[image: Фото файловой системы в Ambari]

Answer (score 1):

Значит так кому интересно, кому нет. Я напишу как у меня получилось запустить.

1. Джарник положил в `/tmp/spark/*.jar`.
2. Колдовство над командой запуска. Вот команда, которая всё это запустила:

   ```
   spark-submit \
       --class movie.Movie \
       --deploy-mode cluster \
       --master yarn \
       --driver-memory 512mb \
       --executor-memory 512mb \
       --executor-cores 1 \
       --num-executors 2 \
       hdfs:///tmp/spark/spark.jar
   ```

   Ошибки которые совершал в команде:

   - `--driver-memory` и `--executor-memory` не меньше 512 мб (при меньших значениях генерируется исключение). Если не ставить - по умолчанию могут стоять большие цифры и у вас просто не хватит ресурсов.
3. Где искать что за ошибка, если статус задачи `FAILED`. Для этого используйте команду

   ```
   yarn logs -applicationId {appId}
   ```

   где `appId` - идентификатор вашего задания. И листаете огромный лог в поисках ошибки. А дальше гугл в помощь.